# Set up a NTP server which can be queried globally

Tags: linux, networking, ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

I want to set up a server (hosted on aws/or a running system in some part of the world) as an NTP server that can be queried globally.

Currently, I have modified the ntp.conf file on the node to be made the server as server . But the problem is, on using an NTP client if I try to query time from this server, or rather on using sudo ntpdate  it says no suitable server found.

However, if I replicate the same on my local network (the server, as well as the querying node, are all on the local network) then this works perfectly fine.

I think the problem might lie in the ntp.conf file. Do I need to put some specific restrict lines for this to work publically as well? And no I cannot list the server on public ntp pages. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: You were asked to provide some diagnostic output at https://askubuntu.com/q/1150187 (strikingly similar to John Mahowald's answer...).  If you want further help, providing the output requested is important.

Answer (score 0):

Start a packet capture. NTP protocol is simple on the wire, you can see if the packets were sent and got a response.

Add the server to `ntp.conf`, and restart ntpd when it is safe to do so. Run `ntpq -p` to see peer status, in particular reach.

The equivalent for chrony is `chrony.conf` and `chronyc sources`.

---

Do not use `ntpdate`. Requires a server argument even if you have configured `ntp.conf`, in other words you needed to do `ntpdate ntp1.example.net`.  It is duplicated NTP code from forever ago, [maintainers have been trying to get rid of it for at least 12 years](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate).